# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word sql-cli

Tags: node.js, sql-server, macos

I'm trying to follow this guide to use mssql with docker in my Mac https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/ but when trying to connect to SQL server I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word error in **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/lib/cli.js:21**

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/lib/cli.js:21
class SqlCli {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
   at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sql-cli/bin/mssql.js:1:76)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Code: (Not mine)

```
...
class SqlCli {
    constructor() {
        this.db = new MSSQLDbService();
        this.messages = new Messages();
        this.options = new Options();
        this.buffer = new Buffer();
    }
...
```

I'm using node version 0.10.35 since this is the one my project is using and I can't change it.

Comment: Your NodeJS version probably doesn't support classes. You either a) Update NodeJS b) Not use any modules that use ES6 Classes (good luck with that). c) transpile everything

Comment: @NikKyriakides, Do you know which is the minimum Node version and could use? Do you know some way for it not to have problems with the version my project uses?

Comment: I've listen some solutions in my comment

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the tutorial you posted and it downloads SqlCli with npm.

When you name a class or file the same as a package in node_modules it will conflict with the node package and ultimately give you this fatal error,

Try changing the class and filename to something different and check again.

```
class DBCli {
    constructor() {
        this.db = new MSSQLDbService();
        this.messages = new Messages();
        this.options = new Options();
        this.buffer = new Buffer();
    }
}
```